# Performing file type counting in all directories

Tags: linux, bash, count

I have a bash script that gives me counts of files in all of the directories recursively that were edited in the last 45 days

```
 find . -type f -mtime -45| rev | cut -d . -f1 | rev | sort | uniq -ic | sort -rn
```

I have a directory called

```
\parent
```

and in parent I have:

```
\parent\a
\parent\b
\parent\c
```

I would run the above script once on folder `a`, once on `b` and once on `c`.

The current output is:

```
     91 xls
     85 xlsx
     49 doc
     46 db
     31 docx
     24 jpg
     22 pub
     10 pdf
      4 msg
      2 xml
      2 txt
      1 zip
      1 thmx
      1 htm
      1 /ic
```

I would like to run the script from `\parent` on all the folders inside `\parent` and get an output like this:

```
+-------+------+--------+
| count | ext  | folder |
+-------+------+--------+
|    91 | xls  | a      |
|    85 | xlsx | a      |
|    49 | doc  | a      |
|    46 | db   | a      |
|    31 | docx | a      |
|    24 | jpg  | a      |
|    22 | pub  | a      |
|    10 | pdf  | a      |
|     4 | msg  | a      |
|    98 | jpg  | b      |
|    92 | pub  | b      |
|    62 | pdf  | b      |
|     2 | xml  | b      |
|     2 | txt  | b      |
|     1 | zip  | b      |
|     1 | thmx | b      |
|     1 | htm  | b      |
|     1 | /ic  | b      |
|    66 | txt  | c      |
|    48 | msg  | c      |
|    44 | xml  | c      |
|    30 | zip  | c      |
|    12 | doc  | c      |
|     6 | db   | c      |
|     6 | docx | c      |
|     3 | jpg  | c      |
+-------+------+--------+
```

How can I accomplish this with bash?

Comment: What does `rev` do and why do you use it?

Comment: i got it from here http://bran.name/dump/bash-build-aggregated-sorted-list-of-file-extensions-in-a-directory-and-count/ i think it just sorts it, i dont know

Comment: looks like the construction `rev | cut -d . -f1 | rev` is an odd (and sort of ingenious) manner of accomplishing `sed 's/\(.*\)\.\(.+\?\)/\2/g'`, which would just extract the file extension from each filename.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put it into a script, make it executable: `chmod +x script.sh` and run it with: `./script.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh

find . -type f -mtime -45 2>/dev/null \
    | sed 's|^\./\([^/]*\)/|\1/|; s|/.*/|/|; s|/.*.\.| |p; d' \
    | sort | uniq -ic \
    | sort -b -k2,2 -k1,1rn \
    | awk '
BEGIN{ 
    sep = "+-------+------+--------+"
    print sep "\n| count | ext  | folder |\n" sep
}

{ printf("| %5d | %-4s | %-6s |\n", $1, $3, $2) }

END{ print sep }'
```

- `sed 's|^\./\([^/]*\)/|\1/|; s|/.*/|/|; s|/.*.\.| |p; d'`

  1. `s|^\./\([^/]*\)/.*/|\1 |` substitutes `./a/file.xls` with `a/file.xls`.
  2. `s|/.*/|/|` substitutes `b/some/dir/file.mp3` with `b/file.mp3`.
  3. `s|/.*.\.| |p` substitutes `a file.xls` with `a xls`, if `s///p` is successful then it also prints to standard out, (to avoid files without extension).
  4. `d` deletes the line (to avoid printing matching (again) or non-matching lines).
- `sort | uniq -ic` counts each group of extension and directory name.
- `sort -b -k2,2 -k1,1rn` sorts first by directory (field 2), small -> large, and then by count (field 1) in reverse order (large -> small) and numerically. `-b` makes `sort(1)` ignore blanks (spaces/tabs).
- the last awk part pretty prints the output, maybe you want to put this into a separate script.

If you want to see how each pipe filters the results just try to remove each and you will see the output.

Here you can find good tutorials about sh/awk/sed, etc.

http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/

Comment: thanks so much for this! i copied and pasted your script into the shell but it gave results only for 1 directory

Comment: Hi, the problem was that `"$@"` holds the arguments passed to the script. If you only copy-paste it into the terminal it will always be empty. Now I changed so you can copy paste the script if you want and it also handles files in current directory.

Comment: hello! thanks so much this works awesomely!!! can you please tell me why does it return only the first 10 or so results for each directory? how can i make it return ALL results for each dir?

Comment: Maybe they are not modified past 45 days, try to remove -mtime -45

Comment: absolutely wonderful answer! thanks so much. can you please tell me what does the sed line do? how were you able to come up with it? it's too fancy

Comment: Haha thank you, you are too kind. :) I tried to explain every part of the sed command as much as possible. I think it is easiest just read the sed chapter from the link above. And try to remove parts of the sed command.